# How to enable/disable a text box on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

For example my page has a text box which already has some value and the readonly option for it is "true" , when the edit button is clicked next to the text box , the editing option in text box is enabled. How do I implement enabling the textbox when i click on a button.

```
function func() {
    $("input:button[name='button1']").click(function() {
        $("#text11").val($(this).val()).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if($(this).val() != "") { 
            $("#text11").attr("disabled", "").focus();
        } 
    });
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="text11" readonly="readonly" value="Editing is disabled">
<input type="button" value="edit" name="button1">
```

which is when I click this button , the readonly option in textbox should be disabled.How do I do that ?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: <html>
<head><title>Edit</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
$("input:button[name='button1']").click(function() {
    $("#text11").val($(this).val()).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      if($(this).val() != "") {
      $("#text11").attr("disabled", "").focus();
      }
});
}
</script>

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code

Comment: What is it you want to do? Your code is quite messy. First you use the readonly attribute, then you use the disabled attribute. Also, what do you want to happen to the text in the text input field? In your code you're initially changing it to the value of the button which is the text "edit".

Answer (score 2):

basically you just want to add the attribute disabled to your element to stop users using it.

```
$('#disablebutton').click(function(){
    $('#textfieldToClose').attr('disable');
});

<input type="text" name="text11" readonly="readonly" id="textfieldToClose">
<input type="button" value="edit" name="button1" id="disablebutton">
```

i believe this should work, haven't tested it mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML DOM objects...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp

Comment: This answer could be uuhhhmmm better imo. 1) You could give some example here on SO instead of just some link. 2) w3schools isn't the best resource out there

Comment: @20911141 w3schools never be a good even ok option so please don't suggest this

Comment: @NullPoiиteя  looks like http://www.w3fools.com/  doesn't have much bad to say about w3schools.  (perhaps it did in the past?).  Absolutely no example there of anything wrong with the site.   Can you provide a  good resource that states the issues with it?